# Difference between plot and plot() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This might seem a very naive thing but I just want to ensure if my understanding is correct.

To plot directly from pandas dataframe as a shortcut, my first option is to call the `plot()` method and pass in my `x` and `y` and the `kind` of the plot I want to make. Otherwise, I can assign the dataframe as a `pandas.plotting._core.PlotAccessor` object to `plot` and then call the appropriate method for plotting like `bar()`, `box()` etc.

So, syntactically I have

```
df.plot(x=x, y=y, kind='something') # call method OR
df.plot.something(x=x, y=y) # assign object and then call method
```

If my above claims are correct, then why I don't get what I intend for univariate plots (hist, box, etc)? Although it works perfectly fine for bivariate ones.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4], 'col2':[3,3,5,5], 'col3':[10,11,12,13]})
df.plot(x='col1', kind='hist') # or
df.plot.hist(x='col2')
```

gives a graph like

[image]

I understand that according to [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/04_plotting.html) I should be using a Series by slicing the `col2` for the same, but then what is the purpose of the `x` and `y`?

Also, this works as expected for bivariate plots like

```
df.plot.scatter(x='col1', y='col3')
```

[image]

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this resource](http://jonathansoma.com/lede/algorithms-2017/classes/fuzziness-matplotlib/understand-df-plot-in-pandas/), `.plot` plots the index against every column, and `.plot()` allows you to specify which columns to plot alone or against other columns.

The reason you weren't getting what you expected for the univariable histogram is because the parameter `x` for the DataFrame method `pd.plot.hist()` is not being used the way you expect.

To get the result I assume you want for a histogram of one variable, you should be using the parameter `y` (as y represents the count of each value of a DataFrame series).

```
df.plot.hist(y='col2')
```

[image]

When you set the parameter `x='col2'` what happens is that pandas traverses `col2` of the DataFrame, and plots a histogram of the values in the other columns (basically treating `col1` and `col3` as `y`). That is why `df.plot.hist(x='col2')` gives you a combined histogram of the `col1` and `col3` values of your DataFrame.

[image]

Comment: Makes total sense. Thanks a ton. Can you also comment on my deductions of the `plot` and `plot()`

Comment: Glad my answer helped! I also added what I think is the best way to understand the difference between plot and plot()